# How to get post data after form submission by asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have the following form in one of my asp.net :

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function GetSampleModel() {
                try {
                    var wldscan = new ActiveXObject("WebLogonDemoClient.WLDScan");

                    var Sl_No = wldscan.GetSl();
                    var sampleModel = wldscan.GetVerifyTemplate();
                    if (sampleModel.length == 0) {
                        alert("Something is Error!!!", "Error");
                    }
                    else { 
                        document.getElementById("scan").Sl.Value = Sl_No;
                        document.getElementById("scan").SampleModel.Value = sampleModel;
                        document.getElementById("scan").submit();
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                    alert("To verify with a fingerprint device, you should install the WebLogonDemoClient software first.", "Software Not Install Error");
                }
            }
        </script>


        <title>Logon</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="GetSampleModel()">
        <form name="scan" id="scan" method="Post" action="" runat="server">
            <input type="Hidden" name="SampleModel" value="">
            <input type="Hidden" name="Sl" value="">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The action of this form is as following :

```
http://localhost/finger/famverifyTX.aspx?name=18&appuser='RANA001'&ailogid='1'&depamount=50&sessid='28902343093145'&custno='18'
```

After form submission, I am trying to get submitted data in another page by the following code :

```
sl = Request.Form["Sl"];
 String SampleModel = Request.Form["SampleModel"];
```

But there is no data in these 2 variables. Where am I doing mistake ? Please help me .

```
NameValueCollection nvclc = Request.Form;
```

After debuggin I am seeing the value of variable as following :

```
{__VIEWSTATE=%2fwEPDwUKLTE4MDU5MzAwNg9kFgICAw8WAh4GYWN0aW9uBUNmYW12ZXJpZnlUWC5hc3B4P25hbWU9JmFwcHVzZXI9JmFpbG9naWQ9JmRlcGFtb3VudD0mc2Vzc2lkPSZjdXN0bm89ZGRLaLIbf6gMRB5SeuUkSj7FHaf%2fRZQuSXp1AE1b4qHvCw%3d%3d&SampleModel=&Sl=&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=9EF55AFD}
```

I have this code :

```
 string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
        var value = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
        {
            // here you get the name eg test[0].quantity
            // keys[i];
            // to get the value you use
            value = Request.Form[keys[i]];
            Response.Write("Keys is " + keys[i] + " and value is " + value+"<br>");

        }
```

This code shows this output :

```
Keys is SampleModel and value is 
Keys is Sl and value is
```

So the value of SampleModel and Sl is nothing . How can I get this value from fmaVerifyTX.aspx page ? Please help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works for me :

```
document.getElementById("Sl").setAttribute('value', Sl_No);
document.getElementById("SampleModel").setAttribute('value', sampleModel);
```